# TypeScript build union type from complex object

Tags: typescript, type-inference, union-types

I have the following `object`:

```
const object = {
  root: {
    path: 'path1',
  },
  paths: [
    {
      path: 'path2',
    },
    {
      path: 'path3',
    }
  ],
};
```

and I would like to build a union type that would look like the following:

`type extractedPaths = 'path1' | 'path2' | 'path3';`

Is there a way to achieve this with TypeScript?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NVZenN) meet your needs?  Note that your definition of `object` needs to be changed (e.g., using a `const` assertion) in order for the compiler to keep track of those strings, otherwise they're all just `string`.  And also note that `const extractedPaths = 'path1' | 'path2' | 'path3'` is not a type but a value and a weird value at that.  Presumably you meant `type ExtractedPaths = ...` instead.  Let me know if this addresses your question and I can maybe write up an answer; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: So, are you likely to accept an answer with that approach or am I missing some requirement you care about?

Comment: @jcalz Sure I'm happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need to change your initialization of `object` so that the compiler knows it's supposed to care about the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `string`-valued properties.  Otherwise you'll get a value of type `{root:{path:string},paths:{path:string}[]}` and then no matter what you do you'll get just `string` out.  So let's use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to get a more specific type for `object`:

```
const object = {
  root: {
    path: 'path1',
  },
  paths: [
    {
      path: 'path2',
    },
    {
      path: 'path3',
    }
  ],
} as const;
```

That gives us the following type:

```
/* const object: {
    readonly root: { readonly path: "path1"; };
    readonly paths: readonly [
      { readonly path: "path2"; }, 
      { readonly path: "path3"; }
    ]; 
  } */
```

Great, the compiler knows about `"path1"`, `"path2"`, and `"path3"`.

---

Then you will need to determine how to identify the types you care about.  One possibility is to recursively descend through the type of `object` and build up a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of any string literal property value types you find along the way.  Here's a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) that does this:

```
type DeepStringLiteralValues<T> =
  T extends string ? string extends T ? never : T :
  T extends readonly any[] ? DeepStringLiteralValues<T[number]> :
  T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]-?: DeepStringLiteralValues<T[K]> }[keyof T] : never;
```

For any type `T`, if `T` is itself a string literal type, then `DeepStringLiteralValues<T>` will just be `T`.  Otherwise, if it's an arraylike type, we evaluate `DeepStringLiteralValues<T[number]>` for each element type of the array.  Otherwise, if it's an objectlike type, we gather the union of `DeepStringLiteralValues<T[K]>` for every key `K` in `keyof T`.  Otherwise, it's not a string or an array or an object, so we ignore it and return `never`.  Let's see what that does:

```
type ExtractedPaths = DeepStringLiteralValues<typeof object>
// type ExtractedPaths = "path1" | "path2" | "path3"
```

Looks good.

---

It's also conceivable that your intent is to just get a union of all recursive properties with the key named `"path"`.  If so you can do this instead:

```
type DeepPropKey<T, K extends PropertyKey> =
  K extends keyof T ? T[K] :
  T extends readonly any[] ? DeepPropKey<T[number], K> :
  T extends object ? { [P in keyof T]-?: DeepPropKey<T[P], K> }[keyof T] :
  never;
```

It's similar to the other version, but `DeepPropKey<T, K>` is trying to find property value types for properties with key `K`, instead of grabbing any string literal it can find.  For your example, it produces the same output, though:

```
type ExtractedPaths = DeepPropKey<typeof object, "path">
// type ExtractedPaths = "path1" | "path2" | "path3"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArApsWBeGBvAUDGATiCFAFzZ74wAOAhlABbkDkdjAjMwDSUC+P+NgwjkA2pXy4qVISyEAmbhJj9lU6TXpMYrLQGYl03pQC6PXjFoQYoSFADcOAPQAqG+GhwkqMhWkFkWgATcAAbAE9CYl8sQkCQsAjNRnIAIiF2VPsVR394sMihETjggphxDWwShKTZGHSteSyVLhhlSWqyuobGPWbjaRNsvhgXJxwJqHDqZBgAEWRkagBlKAIASzAAcwAZdahkAlpQgDVjgFdkCAAeABUAPhh0SluYZAAPA7Ag62gN7ZgAH4YH9Nls3p9kN9rK9gWBkAA3Q4wcivUgvCFfH6dRKRWhgcKiExA+aLFZrMF7A5HU4XK53URgc4AW3ghxMj3R+FeHyx1gQKDQJNiogA0jBNjAANbIcIgABmMFuJgAtIDyAslqt-rt9odjmdQpcbrcxRyVKIZXLFcqUTB4UiCI4cFMZjAAKKfI5oZBBAAKWmsmE15J1VP1tKN9NdyAVXkFUHuzicMBjHq9tB9-sDT3qGVSMAAPnnGgXiz0GH1JtNZiG-URqKLZXdWuLeVDsfWQDMCFMm+FHs98G3IdDpbK47ClWaURj22OAqVcZYCUSSXWG-2GUzWezW5y56PsQKfMLyn6JWBx9alar1aSll3G83TX6zDBRY9eJaJzbiVz7URQ5nTTT01kzA5s0YCB5FzDduy3GM4xPNBWgrVIkycFNQIzLMA2g2DMArTIixLRgmlIis+iAA)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve here but for example you can have something like (check typescript [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsATgQwMbAgEwArOACygF4oByMPfARlKgB8yKCAmWh8ygZlIChRJYCFOiwB5AEYArCOlwFiUAN48oqqE3wAuQUjQYclHjwC%20fcNACaAewCuiCdPQLlaqIitXg2l67Ubt8LoiBgQqasYANGGqGgDOAUJ6YlIywHL4ANoAuiZGqFYAdrHAUAC2IA6p2tZ2lU4kPu6e3tHqlNocBDRRqpFhcdoZrT6u-oyUrD3hU6ojfu3jBNwzUKaqWVHGANxAA))

```
type ExtractedPath = 'path1' | 'path2' | 'path3'
type ExtractedObjectPath = {
    path: ExtractedPath

}
type YourObject = {
    root: {
        path: ExtractedPath
    },
    paths: ExtractedObjectPath[]
}

const myObject: YourObject = {
  root: {
    path: 'path1',
  },
  paths: [
    {
      path: 'path2',
    },
    {
      path: 'path3',
    }
  ],
};
```

Comment: Yes this is a potential solution but you have to define the potential values in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, the whole point of having type is you have to define it in advance. Can you explain it more?